# Cassandra 3.11.6 not starting Windows 10

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am new to Cassandra and I am using Windows 10 for my development. But this time Cassandra is killing my time. I have gone through the documentation, but still have the same problem.

My steps as follows:

1. Windows 10 64 bit.
2. Installed Java jdk-14.0.1.
3. Set JAVA_Home.
4. Installed Cassandra-3.11.3
5. Installed Python.
6. Set necessary environment variables.
7. Set `Execution Policy` as `Unrestricted` for current user in `PowerShell`.
8. Then in `Cassandra\bin` folder runs `cassandra.bat`.

But it showing the following error:

```
PS C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\bin> .\cassandra.bat -f
```

Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.

```
WARNING!  1 swap file(s) detected
    Name: c:\pagefile.sys
It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
for performance and stability reasons.

Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The parameter is incorrect"
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:212 char:5
+     $p.Start() | Out-Null
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:213 char:5
+     $p.WaitForExit()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:214 char:5
+     $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:218 char:9
+     if ($stderr.Contains("Error"))
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:231 char:5
+     $sa = $stderr.Split("""")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:232 char:5
+     $env:JVM_VERSION = $sa[1]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:234 char:9
+     if ($stderr.Contains("OpenJDK"))
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:247 char:5
+     $pa = $sa[1].Split("_")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:248 char:5
+     $subVersion = $pa[1]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:406 char:9
+     if ($env:JVM_VERSION.CompareTo("1.8.0") -eq -1 -or [convert]::ToI ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The parameter is incorrect"
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\bin\cassandra.ps1:251 char:9
+         $p.Start() | Out-Null
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\bin\cassandra.ps1:253 char:9
+         $p.WaitForExit()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

[image: Img1]

[image: Img 2]

[image: Img 3]

Comment: Posting well-formatted error messages is definitely preferable to screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

> 2. Installed Java jdk-14.0.1.

That's the biggest problem I see here.  Current releases of Cassandra only support Java 1.8, so you'll need to have that set up before it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, can you check your JAVA_HOME path in cassandra.bat?
In my case I had to just remove the double quotes from the JAVA_HOME path. 
Something like this:

[image]

This Solved the problem for me. Hope you find it useful.